# Bug in Developers Console when accepting invitation to add Cloud Platform project

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

Well, it would seem that Google ***only*** provide support for Cloud Platform through here, which seems a bit odd, as I've tried to report a bug via their ticketing system only to have it closed with a forward to the Google Product forums, which then got me sent to the slightly-useless Support tab within Cloud Platform itself as there's no forum for Cloud Platform (srsly?), which states "Google engineers monitor and answer questions via Stack Overflow." You'd think they'd have a bloody bug tracker…

Anyway, this is what I submitted via the ticketing system. I'm expecting this to get closed pretty quickly as off-topic, but maybe one of you lot knows where their bloody bug tracking stuff actually is. I can't for a minute believe that they don't have one! >.<

--

Original bug report:

I have discovered a bug in the Google Developers Console (https://console.developers.google.com) regarding the Cloud Platform. When accepting an invitation from another developer to add a project to your console with a Google Apps for Business account which does not yet have any projects created against it (IE, it is a new account), the invitation request process throws the error "You have no more apps available to accept this invitation".

If the user then creates an app against their account directly, then initiates the invitation process, the invitation is accepted as expected, and the project is added to the account as normal. The directly-created project can now be removed, and future invitations work as normal. If all projects are then removed from the apps account, the error "You have no more apps available to accept this invitation." returns again until such time a directly-created project is added.

--

As I said, I'm expecting this to get closed pretty quickly, so if anyone knows where Google's Developers Console bugs should actually be submitted, I'd appreciate it if you could let me know before closing it, as I would expect this post to come up in searches for this bug, and a pointer in the right direction on where to go for support would be of help to me and anyone who comes across this post.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Send Feedback link at the right-bottom corner of the Cloud Console:

https://console.developers.google.com/project

Comment: Christ, could that be any more hidden?! Thanks. Will remain to be seen whether I get a response or not.